# Is there an advantage to using a static method which returns a new instance via a private constructor?

Tags: c#, static, constructor, private

A pattern I occasionally see is like this:

```
public class JustAnotherClass
{
    private JustAnotherClass()
    {
        // do something
    }

    static JustAnotherClass GetNewClass()
    {
        return new JustAnotherClass();
    }
}
```

Why would this ever give an advantage over just having a public constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why would this ever give an advantage over just having a public constructor?

It's a factory pattern. You have a single point where these instances are made.

The advantage would be that in a future extension you could add logic, like returning a derived class instance. Or to return `null` under certain conditions. A constructor cannot return `null`.

Comment: but why should the constructor be private?

Comment: Because the private ctor enforces the use of the factory method.

Comment: sounds evil, so in theory you never can get a `clean` class?

Comment: What would `clean` mean in this context? And when done right, for the right reasons, it's not evil.

Comment: the standard constructor without the data being edited by the factory

Comment: A factory usually doesn't 'edit' any data. But whatever it does might be essential, hence the private (often: protected) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any advantage of having a `static` method just to create a new object. It is more or less equvalent to directly call constructor.

it makes code more scaleable which won't be possible with public constructor. Check [Henk holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman)'s answer also.

Comment: To me, a static method is a 'smell'. It implies that the method should be in another class.

Comment: i also run away from `static` if i can, and it may be factory pattern if the method is moved to different class.

Comment: Why would it be a factory pattern 'if moved to a different class' when the class has only one method?

Comment: What i meant that if moved to different class, the new class is responsible for creation of object of another class, and later may be exteded to create instances of many other classes. so it'll be more near to factory pattern in real time usage.

Answer (score 0):

1. **It can return a derived class.**
   Sometimes you have different internal implementations of a base class, and the consumer shouldn't know which one he got, since it's an implementation detail.
2. **It has a name.**
   I often use it instead of overloading the constructor, so it becomes clearer what the meaning of this new instance is.

One example from a recent project of me: I have a class representing an asymmetric key-pair. The constructor is protected and there are two factory methods:        `FromPrivateKey(byte[])` and `GenerateIdentity()`. IMO this makes consuming code easier to read.

Comment: class can't be drived if it has private constructor.

Comment: @Azodious I think with nesting that might be possible. I typically have a protected constructor in such situations.

Comment: true, missed the nesting derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. The class you show is a factory (see factory pattern). So 'why use a factory' ... as I said a good question.

For me, I use factories when I need to create instances at run time (many times). Why? Because it makes my code some much easier to test using unit testing. This is one answer to you question and it is irrelevant if you do not unit test (and perhaps TDD) your code. No wrongs or rights here, just a fact.

To answer you question ask 'why use a factory'.

Answer (score 0):

Besides from being for flexible, you need this approach if you want to use parameters in your constructor (at least this behavior) and XML serialization at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

As it is in your example there's no real advantage. You use a *factory method* when you want to control when and how instances of your class are created. Some examples:

- You want to implement a *Singleton*, that is always return the same instance;
- You want to implement a *cache* and ensure that new instances are created only when no existing instance is available;
- You need to control when instances are created based on external information. For instance you might be mapping the file system and want to ensure that no two instances of your `File` class exist for the same pathname.